# Are auxiliaries not lexical?

Tags: verbs, lexicon, auxiliary-verbs

Anderson's Essentials of Linguistics says:

> Auxiliaries are what you might have called “helping verbs” when you
> first learned about grammar: they help a **lexical verb** by providing
> grammatical information about a verb’s tense or aspect, or other
> subtle elements of meaning.

Are auxiliaries verbs?

Is there anything not lexical about auxiliaries?

What does lexical mean?
Lexical is the adjective of lexicon, which means the vocabulary of a language. Does a lexicon include auxiliaries?

Answer (score 3):

It's just terminology in this case: a *lexical verb* is a verb that is not an auxiliary.

By most definitions, auxiliaries (ones like "be" and "have", not "will" and "can") are still verbs, because they inflect like verbs. (Though some syntacticians like to put them in their own category, Aux.) And they're certainly words you need to know to know the language.

But "lexicon" (lexical) is sometimes used in opposition to "grammar" (grammatical), and in that sense, auxiliaries are part of the grammar rather than the lexicon—you need to know them to actually parse the language at all, not just to determine the meaning.

Comment: And also auxiliaries can be lexical verbs – the verbs in “I think, therefore I am” and “I have an apple” are lexical in a way that “I think, therefore I’m smart” and “I’ve eaten an apple” are not. With some exceptions in BrE, the lexical uses are not liable to contraction the way the auxiliary uses are.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think it's better to say that "have" has dual classification. It's a lexical verb in "I have a new car" and an auxiliary in "I have bought a new car".

Comment: @BillJ That’s essentially what I meant: some verbs are both lexical verbs and auxiliaries. Whether you consider them two separate verbs or the same verb that’s able to take on two different sets of properties will depend on which framework, creed or hairstyle you prefer to follow.

Comment: @BillJ & Janus Bahs Jacquet Have you no shame?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet & BillJ I've no shame, but that's me.

Comment: @BillJ & Janus See what I did there? :-)

Comment: @draconis   Most syntacticians like to put modal auxiliaries in with the verbs too!